# List not displaying in-line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my list of tags to display in line, but I can't seem to make them to.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.tags{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.tags li:first-child:before {
    content: "Tags:\0000a0";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #7d7d7d;
}
.tags ul li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    background: rgba(239, 177, 113, .4);
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.tags ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(239, 177, 113, .8);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li>Themes</li>
    <li>Code</li>
    <li>Tumblr</li>
</ul>
```

I've also made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sqkk/ (the rgba code doesn't seem to work in jsfiddle - though it's working fine on my actual site).

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline` to `li`

```
.tags li{
    display:inline
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sqkk/1/)**

**OR**

And the problem in your css is you are pointing like this `.tags ul li a` which is wrong because there is no a tag in html and .tags is the class of ul itself so you need not to to write `.tags ul`, make it like `.tags li` it works

**[DEMO 2 Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sqkk/6/)**

Comment: Thank you for the help and coding tips! My CSS works and is cleaner now. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. DEMO 2 link was not updated, i have added new url check it and you can change .tags li:first-child:before into .tags:before

Answer (score 1):

Use `ul.tags` and not `.tags ul`

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sqkk/3/

And the `display: inline-block` must to be on `li` tag

```
ul.tags li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```